# After a few seconds, a method takes longer to execute

Tags: java, optimization, audio, trigonometry

I have this method:

```
public double sineWave(double t) 
{
   return amplitude==0?0:Math.sin(t * frequency * Math.PI*2 + phase) * amplitude;
}
```

It is called by another method in another class to generate a sample of a simple sine wave, which is then added in a buffer to send to the sound card. `t` is the time. For some reason, the more the application calls this method, the slower it gets. It just makes no sense, after 15 seconds it's slow enough to use a full core of my CPU and make the audio stutter.

I'm 100% sure it's this piece of code, because if I replace it with a return 0,  the time it takes to run it (measured with `System.nanotime()`) is constant.

Why is this happening? Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: That's not proof that it's this method; it depends what the rest of your code does with the result!

Comment: Show some more code in the neighbourhood.

Comment: the rest of the application is essentially this
double t=0;
for(;;){
byte[] buff=new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
for(int i=0;i<buff.length;i++){ 
 buff[i]=sineWave(t);
 t+=1/sampleRate;
}
speaker.write(buff,0,buff.length);
}

Comment: if i put system.nanotime before filling the buffer and before writing to the sound card, i see it takes longer and longer every time a buffer is generated

Comment: When you make the method return a constant number, the compiler will most probably optimize away some operations. Your test would have a little more value if, instead of returning zero, you returned a random number within the range of the valid values instead, then see whether the execution speed is closer to the "return zero" version or to the real one and reason accordingly.

Comment: thanks theodoros. i just tried replacing it with a return Math.random(); and the problem doesn't seem to show up

Comment: Math.sin(t) works fine too...

Comment: just made more tests and ... the problem starts as soon as i add frequency to the formula...

Comment: It can be that `Math.sin` does not work well if the argument is very large. You should consider to use a recursion formula for generating a sine wave. This would also be much faster than the repeated sin calculations.

Comment: Trig functions are relatively expensive to call - and if one was not using an already expensive language to implement the audio buffer render in,  a pre-computed look-up table would be the order of the day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the information here - while it is not clear how big your buffer is, you are incrementing t with each iteration. Assuming your frequency is quite high, you are increasing the Sin() argument with each iteration. 
Have checks to see if the argument is constantly increasing to a very high value. 
A quick and dirty test shows that Sin performance goes down -

```
public class SinTest {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    long angle = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    for(long l=0L; l<=1000000L; l++) {
      Math.sin(angle);
    }
    long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    System.out.println(estimatedTime);
  }
}

$ java SinTest 100000
29181000
$ java SinTest 10000000
138598000
```

Comment: If this is the cause of the problem, and I got the same result with a similar benchmark, then I suggest periodically resetting the angle to keep it in a reasonable range.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Only problem now is when can I reset it?

Comment: The Sin function repeats itself after every 2*PI. So Math.sin(angle) and Math.sin(angle + 2*Math.PI) are same, you can reset/mod the angle after each 2*PI

Answer (score 0):

Please give no points, so the solution would be given the answer of @mk:

```
public double sineWave(double t) 
{
    final double TAU = Math.PI *2;
    double a = t * frequency;
    a -= (long)a;
    return amplitude==0?0:Math.sin(a * TAU + phase) * amplitude;
}
```

Comment: I think a recursion formula is better, for example sin(n*x) = 2*cos(x)*sin((n-1)*x) - sin((n-2)*x). 2*cos(x) is constant, and the two sines on the right side are the last two results. This means, you get the next value with one multiplication and one subtraction.

Comment: I think you can replace a-=(long) a with a more efficient a%=1 if you just want to keep the decimal digits

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem with a lookup table:

```
private static final int LUT_SIZE=1000000;
private static double[] sineLookupTable=new double[(int)(Math.PI*2*LUT_SIZE)];
static{
    for(double i=0;i<sineLookupTable.length;i++){
        sineLookupTable[(int)i]=Math.sin(i/(double)LUT_SIZE);
    }

}
private static double sinLUT(double t){
    return sineLookupTable[(int) (((long) Math.floor((t%Math.PI*2)*LUT_SIZE))%sineLookupTable.length)];
}
public double sineWave(double t) {
    return amplitude==0?0:sinLUT(t * frequency * Math.PI*2 + phase) * amplitude;
}
```

it works... kinda, only problem is that i get a lot of distorsion on high frequencies. is there some interpolation method you can suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of the Java framework will attempt to mod-reduce the argument to `Math.sin` using a mathematically-perfect value of 2π, rather than the value `Math.PI*2`.  For code such as yours, this means the code will take longer and yield less accurate results than if mod reduction had been performed using the same scale factor as was used in multiplication (i.e. `Math.PI*2`).  To get good accuracy and speed, you should perform modulo reduction before doing the multiplication, using something like:

```
double thisSpin = t * frequency;
thisSpin -= (thisSpin - Math.Floor(thisSpin)) * 8.0; // value of 0-7.9999=one rotation
switch((int)(thisSpin*8.0))
{
  case 0: return  Math.sin(  thisSpin   * (Math.PI/4.0));
  case 1: return  Math.cos((2-thisSpin) * (Math.PI/4.0));
  case 2: return  Math.cos((thisSpin-2) * (Math.PI/4.0));
  case 3: return  Math.sin((4-thisSpin) * (Math.PI/4.0));
  case 4: return -Math.sin((thisSpin-4) * (Math.PI/4.0));
  case 5: return -Math.cos((6-thisSpin) * (Math.PI/4.0));
  case 6: return -Math.cos((thisSpin-6) * (Math.PI/4.0));
  case 7: return -Math.sin((8-thisSpin) * (Math.PI/4.0));
  default: return 0; // Shouldn't be possible, but thisSpin==8 would be congruent to 0
}
```

That will ensure that neither `sin` nor `cos` is ever used with an argument greater than π/4, which is according to the documentation the point where Java switches to using slow and counterproductive range reduction.